# forward fill all missing values for all variables

Tags: r, tidyr

Consider this simple dataframe

```
> data_frame(var1 = c(NA, 1 , NA),
+            var2 = c (NA, 3, NA))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   var1  var2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1    NA    NA
2     1     3
3    NA    NA
```

I want to fill forward all the missing values for all columns in the dataframe. It seems to me that `tidyr::fill()` can do that, but I am unable to make it work without specifying the columns one at a time.

```
> data_frame(var1 = c(NA, 1 , NA),
+            var2 = c (NA, 3, NA)) %>% tidyr::fill(.direction = 'down')
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   var1  var2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1    NA    NA
2     1     3
3    NA    NA
```

while entering the column name seems to work

```
> data_frame(var1 = c(NA, 1 , NA),
+            var2 = c (NA, 3, NA)) %>% tidyr::fill(var1, .direction = 'down')
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   var1  var2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1    NA    NA
2     1     3
3     1    NA
```

what am I missing here?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert the column names to symbols with `syms` and evaluate (`!!!`)

```
d1 %>% 
  tidyr::fill(!!! rlang::syms(names(.)), .direction = 'down')
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#   var1  var2
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1    NA    NA
#2     1     3
#3     1     3
```

#### data

```
d1 <- data_frame(var1 = c(NA, 1 , NA), var2 = c (NA, 3, NA))
```

Comment: Wonder why all_vars() exists if it cannot be used here... I couldn't figure it out, anyways.

Comment: @Frank there seems to be inconsistency in the documentation `A selection of columns. If empty, all variables are selected`

Answer (score 12):

tidyr verbs accept `dplyr::select` column specifications, so you can use `everything()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data_frame(var1 = c(NA, 1 , NA),
                 var2 = c (NA, 3, NA))

df %>% fill(everything())
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>    var1  var2
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    NA    NA
#> 2     1     3
#> 3     1     3
```

Comment: I like both solutions, but you understand I cannot take back my accept at this stage.. thanks alistaire!

Comment: Hi, I like your answer. I was wondering (and I could not find), is there something like fill_if function, i.e. fill_if(is.character), to be able to select only those columns that satisfy some criteria.

Comment: Not currently, though you could write it. The quickest way may be to use `purrr::modify_if` and fill vector-wise, e.g. `df %>% modify_if(is.character, zoo::na.locf)`